# Is it possible to install Bookworm Testing

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

Can you use Debian Bookworm on a Pi?

How do you upgrade from Bullseye to Bookworm?

What software currently works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally install new OS shortly before official release to test my software.

Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm is probably several months away, but Debian Bookworm was released on 10 June and most of the 64bit code is identical to Raspberry Pi OS so I decided to try.

I chose Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm Lite 64 bit for testing as I expect many Raspberry Pi specific GUI changes.

I followed the normal upgrade process i.e.

1. Do a fresh install of Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye and fully upgrade.
2. Change repository from bullseye to bookworm and update/upgrade.

This worked with only a minor change:-
From non-free to non-free-firmware

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib non-free-firmware
```

I tested both `dhcpcd` (which was inherited from Bullseye) and `NetworkManager`.

---

I installed `gpiod` and `samba`

`RPi.GPIO` and `gpiozero` are present and work as before.

I installed my `pi-gpio` library (which includes a python overlay `pi_gpio`) from the same `deb` file used on Bullseye 64 bit.

All of my code using the above libraries works.

`pigpiod` is missing and not in the repository. There is a note *Currently only the client side is Packaged in Debian as the server side is incompatible with Debian kernels*

Comment: I thought for bookworm you ADD `non-free-firmware` ... i.e.  `main contrib non-free non-free-firmware` - also, you'd want to update `debian-security` and `bullseye-updates` to `bookworm-updates`