# A few questions to Pi4, first post

Tags: pi-4, debian, operating-systems, setup, 64-bit

### Disclaimer

I am a complete newbie when it comes to Raspberry Pi! Please try to take that into account. I do not have prior experience with Pi until yesterday. But I am a rather skilled Linux IT guy, which will come in handy.

---

From a local and official reseller, I bought the whole *starter kit* including the official power adaptor, the official MicroSD with NOOBS software pre-installed, Argon ONE v2 cooling case, apart from cooling it enlarges both micro-HDMI to full-sized HDMIs, and adds the possibility to install M.2 NVMe (or SATA, there are two separate products) SSD at the bottom of the case bonding it to Pi4 with USB 3.0 (and thus limiting the speed). But honestly, I bought the NVMe expansion just because I had an unused NVMe drive of 512GB size. Too small for my other computers.

<strike>[Link to translated store page to English.](https://rpishop-cz.translate.goog/startovaci-sady/5166-1102-sada-s-raspberry-pi-4b-argon-one-v2-32gb-microsd-prislusenstvi.html?_x_tr_sl=cs&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp#/171-velikost_ram-8_gb)</strike>

([Original CZ page if the link gets broken.](https://rpishop.cz/startovaci-sady/5166-1102-sada-s-raspberry-pi-4b-argon-one-v2-32gb-microsd-prislusenstvi.html#/171-velikost_ram-8_gb))

Contents of this kit:

- 1x Raspberry Pi 4 model B with 8GB, [link to the technical specs](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/specifications/)
- 1x Official HDMI cable, 1 meter
- 1x Official 32GB SD card with NOOBS software installed
- 1x Official USB-C source, EU, black
- 1x Argon ONE V2 case (V2 = Version #2)
- 3-Year Warranty (Amazing shop!)

After the assembly, I connected to WiFi (supports 5G), assigned a static local IP to this MAC address, and *fiddled around* just .. a lot. The NVMe drive is showing as `/dev/sda` to note. I measured the Watts and the whole thingy in idle draws just about 7.5W, and when working it spikes to 9W. **Incredible!**

---

Yesterday with the help of many YT videos, and with the help of my family's hands we assembled my very first Pi. **I am thrilled!** 2x 4K HDMI output simultaneously and that is *just for the show*. I do not intend as of right now, to use it for anything else than running a web server.

---

Questions:

- Is NOOBS fit OS to run a web server, or is it there just to install a different OS? The official support said it is more of an *OS installer* than an OS itself, so I strike this one out.

- I have experience with Debian for server use. That may be a better choice, right?
- If so, I found https://raspi.debian.net/tested-images/ and from that table I would likely pick Tested hardware = 4 (8GB) which has a note to it:

> Takes too long to get the wireless lease?

- Does that mean I should wait a bit longer? I mean before deploying it to the Pi.
- Final question is about 64-bit OS, as I do not understand why on 64-bit CPU I should run a 32-bit OS.

Many thanks for reading the whole first post of mine here!

Comment: If someone sold you NOOBS you should demand a refund. It hasn't been supported for 2 years, is NOT an OS and would have installed an old OS.

Comment: Install Raspberry Pi OS from the Raspberry Pi Ltd. website using the official installer.

Comment: The software you linked is pre-release Bookworm experimental code. The official Pi version is some months away. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/143341/8697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry Pi OS 64bit is Debian (they share a common repository).
(This differs from Raspberry Pi OS 32bit where code is recompiled for ARM6.)

The differences are related to the firmware (VideoCore mainly) and support for GPIO (irrelevant for a server).

The GUI DisplayManager etc on Pi desktop are optimised for the limited resources of the Pi, but this is irrelevant for a server.

The Pi does have some weaknesses; in particular the USB power circuitry is not standards compliant and may have problems with external drives (a powered hub is recommended). The Pi (CM4 possibly excepted) has limited support for other storage options.

There should be no difference between Debian & Raspberry Pi OS for server use. There is also a Ubuntu server option available.

---

The question about 64 vs 32 bit has generated considerable discussion over the years. *Raspberry Pi Ltd.* resisted 64 bit (for support reasons) as there is minimal difference in performance.
The advantages would be for applications requiring >2GB of memory.
There is also a wider choice of applications only offered for 64bit OS.

---

I have found no differences in WiFi using `dhcpcd` & `NetworkManager` between  different OS. As it unclear what network manager is used the comment adds little clarity. For a server the wireless lease time is hardly important; indeed using WiFi for a server seems suboptimal (Ubuntu server has no WiFi support).